# Three.js Child of camera isn't visible

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to attach an object to the camera so that it can be used more more or less as a GUI element.

My camera is defined as follows:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, windowWidth / windowHeight, 1, 2000 );
camera.position.z = 100;
```

In my init(), I define the object to be added:

```
    obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF } ));
    obj.position.set( 0, 0, -50);
    camera.add(obj);
```

But, the block does not show up. I have tried adding this object to scene, and it is visible. I added a loop to animate() that will slide the object's z position between (-50, 50), but I can't see it.

I tried using `camera.lookAt(obj)` and logging the world position of obj (obj position + camera position), and they behave as expected. World position seems to be what I'd expect, and camera.lookAt flips the camera when the z position crosses 0.

I apologize for not providing more clear example code, but I will do my best to cooperate with anyone trying to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you add the camera to the scene?

```
scene.add( camera );
```

The camera does not usually have to be added to the scene, but in this case, the object is a child of the camera, so you must.

three.js r.58